# contextMenuStrip add Symbols in Margin C# Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip

I have contextMenuStrip with 6 menu items. In the Margin displayed by default on left, I want to add special characters or Symbols as ↓  on the Margin.

This is not image but special characters added by shortcut on keyboard. Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the character map to select and copy the symbol you want and add it to the Text field of the contextmenu's toolstripmenuitem

[image: Image with symbol in margin]

If you want symbols in place of the image, you should get an image made for that symbol :)